# Custom CSS not loading

Tags: magento2, layout, css

I created a custom css file in Vendor/theme/web/css and added css/custom.css to my default_head_blocks.xml file. Im in developer mode but I still ran static content deploy -f. I cleaned/flushed cache. My custom css still does not show up in the head.

What else is there to check for?

Answer (score 0):

I Hope this is useful for You,

add your CSS file to

app/code/vendor/module/view/frontend/web/css/mycss.css

mycss.css

```
 body{
 background-color:green;

 }
```

Then add CSS File to Your layout File.

app/code/vendor/module/view/frontend/layout/test_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">
   <head>
      <css src="css/mycss.css" />
 </head> 
   <body>
     <referenceContainer name="content">
          <block class="vendor\Module\Block\class" template="vendor_Module::class.phtml"/>
     </referenceContainer>  
 </body> 
</page>
```

Remove this folder

```
 rm -rf var/cache/*
 rm -rf var/page_cache/*
```

Remove pub/static

```
rm -rf pub/static/*
```

Next generate Static Content:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Now, try, Its worked for me. Never forget to add the asterisk behind the folders you're deleting since they contain an `.htaccess` file that might be relevant for your shop to load properly. The asterisk prevents Dot-Files from being deleted.

Answer (score 0):

1. You css file `myfile.css` should be in : `app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{theme}/web/css/myfile.css`
2. Declared in : `app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{theme}/layout/default_head_blocks.xml`

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../vendor/magento/framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
       <head>
           <css src="css/myfile.css" />
       </head>
   </page>
   ```
3. Remove the **CONTENT** of : `pub/static`, `generated`, `var/cache`, `var/page_cache` except the .htaccess
4. launch : `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`

   It should Work.